# Is multicollinearity an issue when doing stepwise logistic regression using AIC and BIC?

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity, aic, stepwise-regression

As far as I understood, it should not be a problem as long as I don't have perfect multicollinearity since I don't mind if the standard errors get inflated. However, what about using the Likelihood-ratio test to do feature selection? I assume, I then need to look for multicollinearity?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of variable selection you have a serious problem with multicollinearity, far beyond the inflated standard errors that can be seen in  linear models that aren't developed via variable selection. A stepwise procedure will tend to choose the predictors that best match your particular data sample, and thus will tend to favor variables that, by the luck of the draw of the sample, happen to have high-magnitude coefficients *for that sample* but not necessarily for the underlying population.

Say that you have 2 correlated predictors. In variable selection, if both contribute equally to fitting your data sample there's a chance that you will miss *both* in your model if they individually are "less significant" than other non-correlated predictors (which happened to have high coefficient magnitudes for your sample) and thus were left out of your stepwise selection. Developing a predictor that combines information from both of the 2 predictors, or an approach like ridge regression, will work better. Alternatively, if one of the 2 predictors ends up substantially better at fitting *your particular data sample*, your estimate of its coefficient could be much higher in magnitude than its true population value, you will lose potentially useful information from its correlated predictor, and the result will not generalize well.

These are among the reasons why advice on this site is almost uniformly to avoid stepwise selection. You can test this advice by repeating your variable selection process on multiple bootstrap samples of your data. You are unlikely to have a very stable selection of "best" predictors among the bootstraps, particularly with multicollinearity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comment - it makes sense. I'd rather not use stepwise regression but I need to for a project I'm participating. So, there is no difference about the need of checking for multicollinearity for the three different criteria (AIC, BIC, LRT)? Thank you again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What about the project requires you to use such a problematic approach?  Note that the more stringency you use in selecting variables the worse stepwise selection performs.  A reasonable default is to use a significance level of 0.5 for keeping a variable.

Comment: Multicollinearity will pose essentially the same issues for all the [closely related criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) you propose. The bigger problem is that the stepwise approach is inconsistent with the assumptions underlying these criteria, which were developed for pre-specified rather than data-driven models. Chi-square tests won't be valid, and it's not clear what the effective number of fitted parameters should be for AIC or BIC.

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers. @Frank Harrell - I'm starting to ask that myself! It's for a university class I'm taking. Can I ask u one last thing. If I run the full logistic model before doing stepwise regression. If I am just interested in prediction and let's say which features are significant, I could basically not do stepwise and make predictions directly. I guess, I wouldn't have a problem with multicollinearity then, right? Thank you so much for the valuable comments!

Comment: That is correct.  Optimum prediction often comes from the full model, and co-linearity does not hurt predictions or the standard error of predicted log odds.  Co-linearity would only hurt if you predict for a future observation that had a different type of consistency between two variables than what was observed in the original dataset (.e.g, a person with a huge waist circumference who weighed very little, and the model had waist and weight in it).

Comment: @ Frank Harrell. Thank you so much for the fast and good reply!